# Type to select friend in Pidgin buddy list

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chat

I use [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) for chat.

Finding a friend in the list is quite painful. Even though friends are listed alphabetically, that does not help much, especially with kanji characters.

I would like to have a way to find by typing, for instance typing `jo` would filter the list on all names that contain that string, like `Joe Lafrite` and `Kali Anjovi`.

Is there any Pidgin plugin/preference/fork/alternative to do that?